# How to use buttons and textbox created dynamically

Tags: c#

i made a program that create many dynamic panel on button "ADD". The thing is that the name of the dynamic panel that have been created is by this way:

```
pArr[counter].Name = "panel" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
```

And so on, so i guess the 5th panel would be named "panel5" if I'm right.

I added some buttons and a Textbox in these dynamically created panels. I don't understand how to use them. I have read a lot of posts in here about it but as its the first time I'm working with this kind of dynamic panels, its hard for me to understand. I found a lot of examples that seems to answer the question but I'm still confused about the names, how to controls buttons and/or textbox.

Per example, how will I set an Event from a button clicked from the 7th panel? It is complicated.

This is my code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f0f0f0");
        Color color2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4285f4");
        System.Random R = new System.Random();
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        TextBox text = new TextBox();
        Button btn = new Button();
        Button btn2 = new Button();
        Button btn3 = new Button();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 10;

        int x2 = 300;
        int y2 = 10;

        int x3 = 380;
        int y3 = 10;

        int x4 = 20;
        int y4 = 13;

        int x5 = 500;
        int y5 = 10;

        int counter = 0;
        Panel[] pArr = new Panel[25];
        pArr[counter] = p;
        
        pArr[counter].Name = "panel" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        pArr[counter].BackColor = color;
        pArr[counter].Size = new Size(panel0.ClientSize.Width, 40);
        pArr[counter].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;           
        pArr[counter].Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        lbl.Text = "Name";
        lbl.ForeColor = color2;
        lbl.Font = new Font("Verdana", lbl.Font.Size);
        lbl.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        lbl.Location = new Point(x4, y4);
        pArr[counter].Controls.Add(lbl);

        text.Name = "txtBox" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        text.Size = new Size(120, 20);
        text.Location = new Point(x, y);
        pArr[counter].Controls.Add(text);

        btn.Name = "btnStart" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        btn.Text = "Start";
        btn.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn2.Font.Size);
        btn.ForeColor = color2;
        btn.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        btn.Location = new Point(x2, y2);
        pArr[counter].Controls.Add(btn);

        btn2.Name = "btnStop" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        btn2.Text = "Stop";
        btn2.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn2.Font.Size);
        btn2.ForeColor = color2;
        btn2.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        btn2.Location = new Point(x3, y3);
        pArr[counter].Controls.Add(btn2);

        btn3.Name = "btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        btn3.Text = "Close";
        btn3.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn3.Font.Size);
        btn3.ForeColor = color2;            
        btn3.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        btn3.Location = new Point(x5, y5);
        pArr[counter].Controls.Add(btn3);

        panel0.Controls.Add(pArr[counter]);
        panel0.AutoScroll = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        panel0.AutoScroll = true;

        counter++;
                    
    }
```

Can someone explain me how to control panels/buttons/textbox?

Comment: You set event just like you always do? Created dynamically or not just attach the event as always when you have a reference to that control.

Comment: @Ralf most peope set events by double clicking the item in the designer and writing code in what appears next. They don't necessarily appreciate the linking `control.Click += somemethod` appears in the .Designer.cs file

Comment: Yes, I know. How do you think `btnAdd_Click` came to be in Homer's code? I think it highly likely, given the context of the question, that they have a `btnAdd` on the form, they double clicked on it and were transported to code view with `private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }` ready to write in, hence the "how the heck does this even work?" question: Homer is potentially completely unaware that `btnAdd.Click += new ...Handler(btnAdd_Click)` has appeared in the Designer.cs

Comment: @Ralf thx for your answer but what is confusing me, is that the user decide to create the number of panels he want. How to set an event for let say "btnStart" on the 20th panel? The button will have the name(btnStart20) i guess but i dont know which buttons will be clicked by the user before he click it. That is what is make me confused.

Comment: @Homer the more important question for us is *what action do you want to happen when the user clicks the btnStart on the 20th panel?*

Comment: @Caius Jard i dont have the "forms" until the user create it dynamically. Its impossible for me to double click on it and write code as its dynamically created.

Comment: I know, so the event handler has to be dynamically attached too.. But *attached to what?* Somewhere you need some code that.. I don't know.. Shuts the computer down or caluclates pi to a billion places.. WHatever it is, you need to dynamically set the click event handler just like you dynamically set the text, and the thing you set the click event handler to needs to call (or be) that shutdown/pi calc code. Tell us the name of the method you want to call when the btnStart is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{       
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f0f0f0");
        var color2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4285f4");
        var r = new System.Random();
        var p = new Panel();
        var lbl = new Label();
        var pnlTxtBox = new TextBox();
        var pnlBtnStart = new Button();
        var pnlBtnStop = new Button();
        var pnlBtnClose = new Button();

        p.Name = "panel" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
        p.BackColor = color;
        p.Size = new Size(panel0.ClientSize.Width, 40);
        p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        lbl.Text = "Name";
        lbl.ForeColor = color2;
        lbl.Font = new Font("Verdana", lbl.Font.Size);
        lbl.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        lbl.Location = new Point(20, 13);
        p.Controls.Add(lbl);
        
        pnlTxtBox.Name = "txtBox";
        pnlTxtBox.Size = new Size(120, 20);
        pnlTxtBox.Location = new Point(100, 10);
        p.Controls.Add(pnlTxtBox);

        pnlBtnStart.Name = "btnStart";
        pnlBtnStart.Text = "Start";
        pnlBtnStart.Font = new Font("Verdana", pnlBtnStart.Font.Size);
        pnlBtnStart.ForeColor = color2;
        pnlBtnStart.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        pnlBtnStart.Location = new Point(300, 10);
        pnlBtnStart.Click += (s,e) => StartWasClicked(pnlTxtBox);       
        p.Controls.Add(pnlBtnStart);

        pnlBtnStop.Name = "btnStop";
        pnlBtnStop.Text = "Stop";
        pnlBtnStop.Font = new Font("Verdana", pnlBtnStop.Font.Size);
        pnlBtnStop.ForeColor = color2;
        pnlBtnStop.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        pnlBtnStop.Location = new Point(380, 10);
        p.Controls.Add(pnlBtnStop);

        pnlBtnClose.Name = "btnClose";
        pnlBtnClose.Text = "Close";
        pnlBtnClose.Font = new Font("Verdana", pnlBtnClose.Font.Size);
        pnlBtnClose.ForeColor = color2;
        pnlBtnClose.Size = new Size(75, 20);
        pnlBtnClose.Location = new Point(500, 10);
        pnlBtnClose.Click += (s,e) => CloseWasClicked(p);
        p.Controls.Add(pnlBtnClose);

        panel0.Controls.Add(p);
        panel0.AutoScroll = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        panel0.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        panel0.AutoScroll = true;           
      
               
    }

    void StartWasClicked(TextBox tb){
        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
    }

    void CloseWasClicked(Panel p){
        p.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant believe it worked... so simple but sooo working. Unbelievable! Thank you 10x my friend. I'm copy paste this whole thread for tutorial to keep!

Answer (score 0):

`pArr` needs to be a member of the class, not a local variable. Then you can simply access `pArr` with an index like any other array.

The panel doesn't even need a name. Names are only useful in the Visual Studio designer so that it can generate the `.Designer.cs` file with a variable name.

As for the events, just add an event handler with  `btn.Click += OnStartClick;` as you would do for a button normally. In the function declaration, you will get `object sender` which identifies the button. You can then use `Array.IndexOf()` [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) to get the index.

```
private void OnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button) sender;
    var panel = button.Parent;
    var index = Array.IndexOf(pArr, panel);
    ...
}
```

Comment: *as you would do for a button normally* - explain this please. Most people that use the forms designer never write `+=` to add an event handler

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really appreciated, would you mind giving me an example on how to make an Event if the btnStart of the 25th panel is being clicked. As we dont know which buttons from which panels will be clicked, how can i set an event?

Comment: @HomerSimpsons Tell us the name of the method you want to call when the btnStart is clicked

Comment: @Caius Jard MessageBox.Show("Button name pressed: " + buttonName + " panel position number: " + panelPositionNb) and when the button "Close" is being clicked, the specific panel is closed. I dont have particular code to run, im just trying to learn.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Thank you, I really appreciate your answer! I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Hokay, so on a comment elsewhere you said you want to

> MessageBox.Show("Button name pressed: " + buttonName + " panel position number: " + panelPositionNb)

It means minimally you can have a code that looks like: (the second to last line is new)

```
    btn.Name = "btnStart" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
    btn.Text = "Start";
    btn.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn2.Font.Size);
    btn.ForeColor = color2;
    btn.Size = new Size(75, 20);
    btn.Location = new Point(x2, y2);

    btn.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show($"Button name pressed: {btn.Name}");

    pArr[counter].Controls.Add(btn);
```

Taking this apart:

```
btn.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show($"Button name pressed: {btn.Name}");
```

- `.Click` is the event of the button. An event is simply a "list of methods that have a particular signature", and when you say `+=` you add a method to the "list of methods that shall be called when the event is raised". There's no defined order; you can add multiple different methods and they will be called, but not necessarily in any particular sequence. `Click` has a type of `EventHandler` which sets out the number and type of arguments any method *must* have in order to qualify as an handler for any event that is shaped like an EventHandler
- `+=` we've covered; if there is an event on the left, then the thing on the right must be a method with a particular signature (dictated by the event signature) i.e. in the case of a button your method on the right must be shaped like an `EventHandler` which means it must have a first argument of type `object` and a second argument of type `EventArgs`. Your `btnAdd_Click` is an example of a method that conforms to those rules
- `(s, e)` is a method signature header. Specifically it's a mini method that we call a lambda. The compiler looks at the event signature and knows that the first thing has to be `object` and the second has to be `EventArgs`; you only have to give *names* - the compiler will fill in the *types*. Actually because we don't even use the names of the arguments in the method code, we could just write `(_, _)` (in .net core+; framework might complain about duplicate names) here which means "no name; throw it away".. But if we did use the variable in the lambda method we'd have to give it a name. We could give them types too: `(object s, EventArgs e)` and it starts to look a lot like a normal method if we do; we don't add these because mostly we don't need to; the compiler can usually figure them out on its own
- `=>` is the thing that separates a lambda method signature from the body
- `MessageBox.Show($"Button name pressed: {btn.Name}")` is the body of the method; the thing that will happen when the button is clicked.

Doing a panel close one:

```
    btn3.Name = "btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
    btn3.Text = "Close";
    btn3.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn3.Font.Size);
    btn3.ForeColor = color2;            
    btn3.Size = new Size(75, 20);
    btn3.Location = new Point(x5, y5);

    var pnl = pArr[counter];
    btn3.Click += (s,e) => pnl.Visible = false;

    pnl.Controls.Add(btn3);
```

Here we take the panel and capture it into a temporary variable. There are specific reasons for doing this, and it doesn't exactly apply to your code as written but I'm assuming at some point you'll upgrade this to use a loop; if we just did `pArr[counter].Visible` C# would take the resting value of `counter` as it was after all the looping is done, and hide *that* panel.. Any button would either cause an error, because `counter` would be off the end of the panels array, or some other wrong panel would hide.

---

We don't have to use these mini-methods (lambdas); we can pass this data around another way if you like..

Taking the example of the panel hide, because it's actually doing something interesting with the UI. Let's have a method that hides a panel that it finds in the `Tag` of the control in the `sender`:

```
private void HidePanelInTag(object sender, EventArgs e){

  //get the sender as a button; we will only ever attach this code to buttons that have a Panel in their Tag
  var b = sender as Button;
  
  //get the Tag from the button and cast it to a panel
  var p = b.Tag as Panel;

  p.Visible = false;
}
```

Now we can tweak the loop that is creating the `btn3` close buttons:

```
    btn3.Name = "btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
    btn3.Text = "Close";
    btn3.Font = new Font("Verdana", btn3.Font.Size);
    btn3.ForeColor = color2;            
    btn3.Size = new Size(75, 20);
    btn3.Location = new Point(x5, y5);

    btn3.Tag = pArr[counter];
    btn3.Click += HidePanelInTag;

    pnl.Controls.Add(btn3);
```

We've stored the panel in the Tag - this varies for every button, a different Panel. The event handler attachment looks simpler too, because whereas a lambda has a full method (header, and body) defined on the line it is encountered, in more old fashioned terms the method definition is separated from its use:

```
btn3.Click += HidePanelInTag;
```

Remember before we said `+=` separates an event on the left, from a method on the right; so long as the method on the right obeys the signature of the event, we're allowed to "add it to the list of methods that are called when the event is raised".

When the button is clicked, `HidePanelInTag` is called. Windows Forms automatically puts the control that is raising the event (the button) into the `object sender` argument. That's how we retrieve the Panel to hide; every button has a different Panel in its tag. If you click the 25th button, the `sender` is the 25th button, and the `Tag` is the 25th panel

---

End of the day there are loads of ways to skin this cat. For example you don't have to store a panel in a button's Tag.. You could even do some crazy like this:

```
btn3.Click += (s, e) => {
  var b = s as Button;
  var pname = b.Name.Replace("btnClose", "panel");
  var p = panel0.Controls[pname];
  p.Visible = false;
};
```

Get the button name, change it to be what the panels name is, find the panel by name, hide it... All in a multi-line lambda. That's kinda nasty, just treat it "for educational purposes" - ultimately all these buttons you make  end up stored in tree of controls (your form has a penal that has panels that have buttons..) that can be searched, so "name" does have a use.. But we probably wouldn't use it for this approach.

The main take-away from this is that *just like setting the name, the text, the position etc **dynamically***  you also need to wire up the click events dynamically. That's done using `event_name_here += event_handler_method_name_without_parentheses_here`; in this regard methods aren't really any different from data variables in the way they're passed around by name

---

#### Passing Methods Around Like We Pass Data

Edit, following on from a comment below

You're comfortable with Properties:

```
btn3.Name = "btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);
```

Events are nearly exactly the same:

```
btn3.Click += (s,e) => pnl.Visible = false;
```

Let's have a table:

| Property, `btn3.Name` | Event, `btn3.Click` |
| --- | --- |
| receives a string | receives a method |
| set with `=` | set with `+=` |
| can receive any string you want, for example `"btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1)` | can receive any method you want, so long as the method has two arguments: an object and an EventArgs, for example `(s,e) => pnl.Visible = false` |

Once you're happy that the following two things are essentially *both methods*, one called GetTime, and one without a name (because it doesn't need one):

```
(n) => "Hello " + n + ", the time is " + DateTime.Now;

public string GetTime(string n){
  return "Hello " + n + ", the time is " + DateTime.Now;
}
```

the only mental block you might have, that we need to unblock, is this idea of "passing methods around like we pass data around".

Methods typically *produce* data when you call them, so you're used to using a method to produce data and assign data:

```
btn3.Text = GetGermanTranslationFor("Close");
```

That will call the method `GetGermanTranslationFor` passing in "Close", and the method returns "Schließen", then "Schließen" will be set as the text - that was all "passing data around"

But suppose a button had a `MethodToCallToGetTheText` property where instead of setting the data, we set *the method to call to get the data* and then button *will call that method itself*:

```
btn3.MethodToCallToGetTheText = GetGermanTranslationFor
```

There is no `(` after the method name here; we don't want to *call the method ourselves*.. We want to *give the method to the button* so the *button* can call it.

This is what events are intended to do; a way of saying "here, when the click happens, call this method I'm giving you".

- Microsoft can write a Button but they can't know what text I will put on it, so they provide a Text property and I set it myself
- Microsoft can write a Button but they can't know what what code I'll run when the user clicks it so they just provide a facility where they say "put a method here, with these certain parameters, and we'll call it when the user clicks"

As it happens, Microsoft decided that the "put a method here" should actually be "put one or more methods here", which is why we use `+=` to wire them up (because events are like a list of methods that you add to) but other than that, the theory is the same as setting a property; passing methods round like data is very useful

Comment: Ohh if i understand it correctly, the btn.Name is not the name of the variable we are calling? The way im understanding this is that when you create dynamic panels, "Button btnStart = new Button()" will actually do the same work all over each created panels? Do im right? btn.Name is just a given name that cant be called for action/event? It's well explained, thank you. The last thing that bugging me is how to close a specific panel on btnClose click?

Comment: I understand all the code im doing a developper degree  so i understand most of codes but as i dont have alot of experiences, there is alot of things that i still need to learn.

Comment: I've edited in some words about the panel closing

Comment: btn.Name is just a text property. It has uses like.. you can find controls by name (and i added an example how we could possibly use it to solve some similar problem.. But given that we already know the panel and the button when we make the button, the simplest thing is to wire things up in such a way that we can use that panel we know about directly.. One thing to keep in mind is what I mentioned about C# capturing variables it sees you using in a loop. If you put that variable into the code body of a lambda, it doesn't resolve to the *value applicable at the time the loop ran* ..

Comment: ..it resolves to "the value of the variable when the lambda code is run" - which for a loop variable being incremented every time can give unexpected results. Make a note to yourself; if you write a lambda that uses a variable, be mindful of changing the value of that variable after you already made the lambda

Comment: Wow such a detailed explaination. Awesome, from here i will probably being able to make my way with the same logic as you used. A big thank you for the longs and detailed answers all along the post. Much appreciated!

Comment: I just realized one small thing - this code has the hallmarks of a loop that was removed - counter being inited to 0, and `++`'d but neeedlessly - i'll leave the advice about capturing loop variables in in case you put a looping construct in later

Comment: i managed to close the panel. I studied your explaination. It was really detailed. If i may ask, would you mind to explain me how can i get the text of a textbox in these dynamics panel. It is so confusing that since yesterday i didnt figured out how to apply your explaination to the textbox. I may sound dumb but its really confusing as i just started learning about dynamic controls. Thank you

Comment: So, let's assume you're adding another button `btn4` whose job it is to get the text out of textbox `text` and show it on screen. That would be `btn4.Click += (s,e) => MessageBox.Show(text.Text);`. Or maybe you have a method `ProcessFile(string whatFile)` and the user is supposed to put the path into the textbox next to the Start button and click the Start button `btn`.. that's `btn.Click += (s,e) => ProcessFile(text.Text);`

Comment: Ultimately, you just need to keep going back to that simple rule -> "if the button is added dynamically, the click event of the button needs to be linked up dynamically too". Just like you set the dynamic button name with some dynamic string thing: `btn3.Name = "btnClose" + (panel0.Controls.Count + 1);` you are also setting the button click in the exact same way with some dynamic method thing: `btn3.Click += (s,e) => { SomeCodeHere };`

Comment: I made an edit.. Read from Passing Methods Around...

Comment: Big thank you, i will study it carefully as it is so much well detailed. Much appreciate!!!

Comment: When i try to do it the only thing it give me its the value of the last created dynamic panel textbox.

Comment: Really need to see the full exact code you've written. It sounds like you're running into some variation of the "but watch out for what will happen if you do this in a loop without making a temp variable" trap i mentioned in the post

Comment: I added my code and a pic of the result.

Comment: It's because you have a `pnlTxtBox` as a class level control, so every time you click Add you set it to a new thing, but when you access it you aren't accessing the dynamically created one, you're accessing the class-level one, which was most recently overwritten by the `pnlTxtBox = new ...` in the Add click. You've got a bit of a hybrid setup going on, where you're mixing dynamic and non-dynamic controls. I wouldn't recommend it. All those things at the top of the class (from `Color color;` to `Button pnlBtnClose;`.. put them inside the `btnAdd_Click` instead,so you can't use them incorrectly